# Get file ID after upload using JSOM

Tags: file-upload, client-object-model, document-id

I use JSOM to upload document in library.
I use this JS:

```
var file;
var fileCreateInfo;
function CreateFile()
{
    // Ensure the HTML5 FileReader API is supported
    if (window.FileReader)
    {
        input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
        if (input)
        {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedBinary;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("The HTML5 FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
    }
}

// Callback function for onload event of FileReader
function receivedBinary()
{

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://pk-sp:88//');
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(this.oWebsite); 
    var list = this.oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents"); 

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url(file.name);
    fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());

    // Read the binary contents of the base 64 data URL into a Uint8Array
    // Append the contents of this array to the SP.FileCreationInformation
    var arr = convertDataURIToBinary(this.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    {
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(arr[i]);
    }

    // Upload the file to the root folder of the document library
    this.newFile = list.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.newFile);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}

function onSuccess()
{
    // File successfully uploaded
    alert("Success!");
}

function onFailure()
{
    // Error occurred
    alert("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
    console.log("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
}

// Utility function to remove base64 URL prefix and store base64-encoded string in a Uint8Array
// Courtesy: https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI)
{
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

How can i get Id of uploaded file?

I can use SPServices library to get last id or find by Title.
But I think that the best way to get this ID from the fileCreateInfo object. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the ID from newFile, check out [SP.File.listItemAllFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244878%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

You'll need to include the property in your load:

```
clientContext.load(newFile, 'ListItemAllFields');
```

Then you can access the ID with:

```
newFile.get_listItemAllFields().get_id();
```

Comment: Hello, this helpd me. But i was looking for a way to update the file, when it is uploading. Thank u @Anders Aune